# When two SSIDs are created on Netgear WNDAP350 can they each have their own subnet?

Tags: wireless, dhcp, subnet, netgear-prosafe

I work for a very small company with an akward shaped building.  As a result we have 3 Netgear WNDAP350 Dual Band Simultaneous Access Points to cover everywhere.  They've been setup and running for about a year now maybe without any issues.  The 2.4Ghz and the 5Ghz SSIDs are different names but each of the three access points are setup identically otherwise so that no matter where you are in the building you only see the two SSIDs so everyone is happy.

One thing I wonder though is if it is possible to assign a different subnet to each of the two different SSID's?  Right now they both assign IP addresses from our DHCP server from just the 10.10.xxx.xxx scope.  DHCP is NOT being handled on the Netgear Access Points.  What I would like to setup if possible is something like the following:

SSID2.4ghz - 10.10.xxx.xxx
SSID5ghz - 10.11.xxx.xxx

Both subnets already exist; I'm just not educated enough yet to know how(if possible) to set it so that the two different SSIDs run on the different subnets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [VLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN)  and Trunking.

In short you do have to trunk the interface that links the switch and the AP, and the interface that links the switch with the DHCP server. In this way you will have somethink like ethx.y (in a Linux fashion) or Ethernetx.y (in a Cisco fashion) where x is the identifier of the interface and y is the VLAN tag.

On the access point you need to "bridge" every SSID with the sub-interface according to the chosen VLAN.

On the DHCP server you have to define a specific pool according to the sub-interface from where the request comes from, and therefore the VLAN from where it comes from.